# Code golf edit distance up to 3

Tags: code-golf, restricted-time

The **edit distance** between two strings is the minimum number of single character insertions, deletions and substitutions needed to transform one string into the other.

This task is simply to write code that determines if two strings have edit distance at most 3 from each other.  The twist is that your code must run in **linear time**. That is if the sum of the lengths of the two strings is `n` then your code should run in `O(n)` time.

## Example of strings with edit distance 2.

```
elephant elepanto
elephant elephapntv
elephant elephapntt
elephant lephapnt
elephant blemphant
elephant lmphant
elephant velepphant
```

## Example of strings with edit distance 3.

```
   elephant eletlapt
   elephant eletpaet
   elephant hephtant
   elephant leehanp
   elephant eelhethant
```

## Examples where the edit distance is more than 3. The last number in each row is the edit distance.

```
elephant leowan 4
elephant leowanb 4
elephant mleowanb 4
elephant leowanb 4
elephant leolanb 4
elephant lgeolanb 5
elephant lgeodanb 5
elephant lgeodawb 6
elephant mgeodawb 6
elephant mgeodawb 6
elephant mgeodawm 6
elephant mygeodawm 7
elephant myeodawm 6
elephant myeodapwm 7
elephant myeoapwm 7
elephant myoapwm 8
```

You can assume the input strings have only lower case ASCII letters (a-z).

Your code should output something Truthy if the edit distance is at most 3 and Falsey otherwise.

If you are not sure if your code is linear time, try timing it with pairs of strings of increasing length where the first is all 0s and the second string is two shorter with one of the 0s changed to a 1.  These all have edit distance 3. This is not a good test of correctness of course but a quadratic time solution  will timeout for strings of length 100,000 or more where a linear time solution should still be fast.

(This question is based on this [older one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/202974/code-golf-edit-distance-2))

Comment: Why? Does changing the edit distance from 3 to 2 make a big difference with the older question? (Also it seems that the older question was also asked by you)

Comment: @wasif Yes it does. The tricks for distance 2 no longer work and you need new tricks.

Comment: I think you are lacking new challenge ideas. Simple idea:figure out the edit distance of two strings

Comment: I agree with @wasif I feel this question is too similar to the previous one.

Comment: @EliteDaMyth The edit distance is normally computed via dynamic programming. See e.g. https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Python . This takes quadratic time. For fixed distances it is however possible to compute it in linear time. A general algorithm to do this is via a variant of the dynamic programming algorithm . However for specific small but fixed distance you can do it with shorter code with some thought and tricks.  Distance 1 is really easy, 2 a little trickier and 3 a little more tricky again. They really are different questions.

Comment: @Anush The general k-edit distance problem would be a nice challenge in the future too.

Comment: @wasif "figure out the edit distance of two strings " is a very different question and I think has been asked here previously.

Comment: If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32558749) runs in linear time, I have a 3-byter in Vyxal.

Comment: I think [Wheat Wizard's answer for distance 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/202980/78410) is easily modifiable to any constant edit distance, and I doubt any other methods are viable for distance higher than 2.

Comment: @Bubbler. I can’t tell how fast that Haskell approach would be but that is interesting if it can be made to work. The most straightforward way to approach my question is to look at only the part of the dynamic programming table that is at most 3 cells to the left and right if the diagonal.  There may be other ways I haven’t thought of too.

Comment: @Anush Your last comment shows very well that the challenge would've been better with the third input (target edit distance) instead of constant 3.

Comment: @Bubbler I almost agree :)  I wanted to avoid having to make the complexity reasoning complicated to think about. If I set the constant to 3 then everyone can see what linear time means and also it is easy to test to check it is running fast enough. If the max distance is a parameter then the only way to know its complexity is to reason about the code which is more difficult potentially.

Comment: Adapt [answer for that question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233856), and to [this needs only mirror changes](https://tio.run/##ldJRT8IwEADgd37FPUkbShPEqQmWNx/9BXMJ13Gwka5r2Akx4m/HDUU32Ivpw12/3l2TphvcYZVu88BjXy7puDJHNHNr5qi3tHxLSQhWqcqlmbMuMAjh1abeBPOCnOki98KPRWqMjfPRZjxNpAqK481okhwOkRxNVDCRVHGkmjVRt2qq7hIZW@3Irzkb408ymiZP0ZGp4hQrqsDAYkCOQoaeoUnqWHYlw@B512P8Z2f6E@uoOGWtokvYNdm3dcazw8BdCUgtyerI3dlEdQytJnIZ8cVsR@UePdxdim1T0WP95C5p/WNR15a9trdw37r1f1Z07P2MD23sK2wsXBde2zc9Dhaat3khpK6Cy1kMX/1Qzga/H0ivyu0zpplwuScwc/gYQP00DDEqsEn9v5qDczM0vQD5CgTCzQ1YCWnpq9KRduVarESstcZEnqJNZF39KWfHLw) for me

Comment: @tsh could you add that as answer here? It looks very clever

Comment: My Haskell answer is indeed easily modifiable for any \$n\$, as simple as replacing `2` with `3` and `==` with `>`. In general the algorithm used there is \$O(3^nm)\$ where \$n\$ is the maximum edit distance and \$m\$ is the sum of the lengths of the strings.  This makes it \$O(m)\$ when \$n\$ is fixed.

Comment: @WheatWizard very impressive. I find the answer of tsh particularly amazing. I am hoping people will port either of your answers to other languages.

Comment: I've closed this as a dupe of the earlier challenge. As discussed in chat last week, and evidenced by WW's answers, this is essentially that same task

Comment: Oh well......:)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>93</s> 90 bytes

```hs
x%y=[0,0,0]>=x#y
u@(a:b)#v@(c:d)|a==c=b#d|k<-zipWith(+)=0:k(d#u)(k(b#v)$b#d)
a#b=a++b>>[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBda4MwFIbv8yskVkxwLfZWFikMdjWYsIsNxIsTk9bgJ/WjdfS3z@lcqa6yBHKS533hvCcRlLFMkq47Gy3z7Yd@By476y2qdwQcTvVmR0JH0AswFjKui0v8uP5UxbuqImJRZjsxEXpNSUy43tBV76AIdM7Asrjr@nbQpZC1ryXzt5vN1v5ZgeviHCOUgsqYyJGmFXX1Vh1fMg17UJaydPAAjyqrVhh4KLCB@1NOKF@kMpFFBFnVK81wHx@LepL@J8r8NBd/U8ihTGiP4A8ajXBDxOSmY4amM/4ENcaKZnM/g0pmY9@nURP1vu/Uf5C5gBNfiGCKawzLwnt8zdJ9hfsEDmW3/njyvG8)

This is taken from [this previous answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/202980) with basically no modification.

### How it works:

We start by looking at a naive version of edit distance:

```haskell
lDistance :: ( Eq a ) => [a] -> [a] -> Int
lDistance [] t = length t   -- If s is empty the distance is the number of characters in t
lDistance s [] = length s   -- If t is empty the distance is the number of characters in s
lDistance (a:s') (b:t') =
  if
    a == b
  then
    lDistance s' t'         -- If the first characters are the same they can be ignored
  else
    1 + minimum             -- Otherwise try all three possible actions and select the best one
      [ lDistance (a:s') t' -- Character is inserted (b inserted)
      , lDistance s' (b:t') -- Character is deleted  (a deleted)
      , lDistance s' t'     -- Character is replaced (a replaced with b)
      ]
```

(I wrote this program for Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Recursive))

This is pretty bad because every time it finds a discrepancy between the two strings it branches into 3 options (insert, delete or replace) so in the worst case it will have the time complexity of \$O(3^n)\$.

The thing to notice though is that whenever we branch we increase the total distance by 1.  So if we are on a particular search path that has already branched 3 times and we would branch another time. So we can just stop there and say return `False` for this branch since it can never find the result.

Now there is a hard limit on the number of branches that can occur, \$3^3 = 27\$, so our computation is \$O(n)\$.

In general this strategy has a complexity of \$O(3^mn)\$ where \$m\$ is the limiting distance.

Comment: This is a very nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 120 bytes

```
_+[]+[].
N+[A|B]+[A|C]:-!,N+B+C.
N+[_|B]+C:-N>0,N-1+B+C.
N+B+[_|C]:-N>0,N-1+B+C.
N+[_|B]+[_|C]:-N>0,N-1+B+C.
B*C:-3+B+C.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/P147OhaI9Lj8tKMda5xiQaRzrJWuoo6ftpO2M1g8HiTubKXrZ2eg46drCBN3AsmA1KKJQ9Rjk3PSAppiDGb/t9JViDbSgUFDHaNYrWhDHRCE8fX@cwEA)

This is the same basic algorithm as [my Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233905/56656), but it implements it using Prolog's built in search.

We have to add a cut on the second case

```
N+[A|B]+[A|C]:-!,N+B+C.
```

If we don't the will try to branch even when the first two characters are the same.  This will cause exponential branching with respect to the length of the string.

The cut here ensures that if the first two characters are the same we don't backtrack.

The Haskell answer doesn't have this issue because Haskell will eagerly follow the first path of execution.

Comment: This reads like an advert for Haskell :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 109 bytes

```
_+[]+[].
N+[A|B]+[A|C]:-!,N+B+C.
\N+B+C:-B=[_|X],N+X+C;C=[_|Y],N+B+Y;B=[_|X],C=[_|Y],N+X+Y.
B*C:- \ \ \a+B+C.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/P147OhaI9Lj8tKMda5xiQaRzrJWuoo6ftpO2sx5XDJi20nWyjY6viYgFCkdoO1s7g3iRsWBFkdYwOYRohHakHpeTFlCfQgwIJoIN@/8/2kgHBg11jGK1og11QBDG1@PiAgA)

This is a golf of [Wheat Wizard's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235192/20059). The key modification I made was that instead of using Prolog's built in numbers and arithmetic to keep track of the the current edit distance, I instead used nested compound terms, built using the unary operator `\`. Thus instead of having to check if `N` is greater than zero and then use subtraction, I can roll both of those steps into a single pattern match by matching the current remaining edit distance to `\N`. This left me with the following program (111 bytes):

```
_+[]+[].
N+[A|B]+[A|C]:-!,N+B+C.
\N+[_|B]+C:-N+B+C.
\N+B+[_|C]:-N+B+C.
\N+[_|B]+[_|C]:-N+B+C.
B*C:- \ \ \a+B+C.
```

I managed to save a couple more bytes by merging the latter three rules for the `+` predicate into a single rule, as described [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67032/20059).

Comment: Thank you for sneaking under the wire!